# How to change property of object in React, Recoil

Tags: reactjs, state, recoiljs

I'm working on a shopping cart.
`<Cart />` is Cart Page which render Products in cartList Array.
`<CartProduct />` render each one product in cartList Array

[image]

I want to make the quantity data change, when i click quantity button.

Here is My First Try Code

```js
function Cart(props) {
    const cartsList = useRecoilValue(cartsListState);

    return(
        {cartsList
           .filter(cart => cart.keep === 'cold')
           .map((cart) => {
                return <CartProduct cart={cart} getNowQuantity={getNowQuantity} />
            })
         }
       {cartsList
            .filter(cart => cart.keep === 'freeze')
            .map((cart) => {
                return <CartProduct cart={cart} getNowQuantity={getNowQuantity} />
              })
        }
       {cartsList
            .filter(cart => cart.keep === 'normal')
            .map((cart) => {
                 return <CartProduct cart={cart} getNowQuantity={getNowQuantity} />
             })
        }
     )
}
```

```js
function CartProduct({ cart, getNowQuantity}) {
    const [cartsList, setCartsList] = useRecoilState(cartsListState);
    
    return(
        const PlusQuantity = () => {
            setCounterQuantity(counterQuantity => counterQuantity + 1);
            cart.quantity += 1;
            getNowQuantity(cart.quantity);
    }

    const MinusQuantity = () => {
        if (cart.quantity>=2) {
            setCounterQuantity(counterQuantity => counterQuantity - 1);
            cart.quantity -= 1;
            getNowQuantity(cart.quantity);
        }
        else return;
    }
    )
}
```

Firts code make error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of
> object '#

So i tried to use spread operator in `CartProduct.js` Like this way

```js
const cartProduct = ([ ...cart]);
 
return(
   CartProduct.quantity = +1 
~~
~~~
)
```

This code make error

> cart is not iterable

so i tried

```js
let iterableCart = cart[Symbol.iterator]
```

It doesn't work.

How can i change `cart.property` for ChangeQuantityButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Recoil makes everything immutable so code like this

```
cart.quantity += 1;
```

won't work because you're trying to update a value on a frozen object.

Instead you need to create a new object, and use the existing values to update it.

Here I'm using a sample data set and using it to build three product items using an `<Item>` component. This component displays the name, the current quantity, and two buttons to decrement/increment the values. On the buttons are a couple of data attributes that identify the product id, and the button action.

When a button is clicked the `handleClick` function is called. This destructures the `id` and `action` from the button dataset, and then `map` over the current cart using those values to check the cart items and return updated objects to the state.

```js
const { atom, useRecoilState, RecoilRoot } = Recoil;

// Initialise the cart data
const cart = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Banana', qty: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Beef', qty: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Mop', qty: 0 }
];

// Initialise the cart atom setting its
// default to the cart data
const cartAtom = atom({
  key: 'cartAtom',
  default: cart
});

function Example() {

  // Use the recoil state
  const [ cart, setCart ] = useRecoilState(cartAtom);

  // When a button is clicked
  function handleClick(e) {

    // Get its id and action
    const { dataset: { id, action } } = e.target;

    // Update the cart using the id to identify the item
    // and return an updated object where appropriate
    setCart(prev => {
      return prev.map(item => {
        if (item.id === +id) {
          if (action === 'decrement' && item.qty > 0) {
            return { ...item, qty: item.qty - 1 };
          }
          if (action === 'increment') {
            return { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 };
          }
        }
        return item;
      });
    });

  }

  // Iterate over the cart data using the Item
  // component to display the item details
  return (
    <div>
      {cart.map(item => {
        const { id, name, qty } = item;
        return (
          <Item
            key={id}
            id={id}
            name={name}
            qty={qty}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

}

function Item({ id, name, qty, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <span className="name">{name}</span>
      <button
        data-id={id}
        data-action="decrement"
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >-
      </button>
      {qty}
      <button
        data-id={id}
        data-action="increment"
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >+
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <RecoilRoot>
    <Example />
  </RecoilRoot>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.item:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 0.25em; }
.name { display: inline-block; width: 60px; }
button { width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: 0 0.25em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/recoil@0.7.6/umd/index.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```